# ngCsp directive in chrome extension when angular is initialised by angular.bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have some problem, because my extension is adding to the DOM of some pages my own sidebar which is written in angular 1.5.

Because of that I'm initialising my angular app by angular.bootstrap:

```
angular.bootstrap(null, ['app']);
```

Right now I'm receiving this kind of error in my console, when I'm not using 'unsafe-eval' in my manifest.json file:

```
(v6.92) Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://www.googleadservices.com/".
```

Do You have any ideas, how to use this directive in my extension to avoid this errors (my extension isn't working when this error appears).

Comment: "when I'm not using 'unsafe-eval' in my manifest.json file", do you want to avoid these errors without setting `unsafe-eval` in `manifest.json`?

Comment: 100% same as above question.